# How one deals with multiple pointer level (like char**) in Squeak FFI

Tags: smalltalk, ffi, squeak

I want to deal with a structure like this `struct foo {char *name; char **fields ; size_t nfields};`

If I define corresponding structure in Squeak

```
ExternalStructure subclass: #Foo 
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'FFI-Tests'.
```

and define the fields naively with

```
Foo class>fields
    ^#(
        (name 'char*')
        (fields 'char**')
        (nfields 'unsigned long')
      )
```

then generate the accessors with `Foo defineFields`, I get those undifferentiated types for name and fields:

```
Foo>>name
    ^ExternalData fromHandle: (handle pointerAt: 1) type: ExternalType char asPointerType

Foo>>fields
    ^ExternalData fromHandle: (handle pointerAt: 5) type: ExternalType char asPointerType
```

That is troubling, the second indirection is missing for the fields accessor.

How should I specify fields accessor in the spec?
If not possible, how do I define it manually?

And I have the same problem for this HDF5 function prototype: `int H5Tget_array_dims(hid_t tid, hsize_t *dims[])`

The following syntax is not accepted:

```
H5Tget_array_dims: tid with: dims
    <cdecl: long 'H5Tget_array_dims'(Hid_t  Hsize_t * * )>
```

The compiler barks `argument expected ->` before the second `*`...
I add to resort to `void *` instead, that is totally bypassing typechecking - less than ideal...

Any idea how to deal correctly with such prototype?

Answer (score 1):

Since Compiler-mt.435, the parser will not complain anymore but call back to `ExternalType>>asPointerToPointerType`. See [source.squeak.org/trunk/Compiler-mt.435.diff](http://source.squeak.org/trunk/Compiler-mt.435.diff) and [source.squeak.org/FFI/FFI-Kernel-mt.96.diff](http://source.squeak.org/FFI/FFI-Kernel-mt.96.diff)

At the time of writing this, such pointer-to-pointer type will be treated as regular pointer type. So, you loose the information that the external type actually points to an array of pointers.

When would one need that information?

- When coercing arguments in the FFI plugin during the call
- When constructing the returned object in the FFI plugin during the call
- When interpreting instances of `ExternalData` from struct fields and FFI call return values
- In tools such as the object explorer

There already several kinds of `RawBitsArray` in Squeak. Adding `String` and `ExternalStructure` (incl. packed or union) to the mix, we have all kinds of objects in Squeak to map the inner-most dimension (i.e., int*, char*, void*). `ExternalData` can represent the other levels of the multi-dimensional array (i.e., int**, char**, void** and so on).

So, there are remaining tasks here:

1. Store that pointer dimension information maybe in a new external type to be found via `ExternalType>>referencedType`. We may want to put new information into `compiledSpec`. See http://forum.world.st/FFI-Plugin-Question-about-multi-dimensional-arrays-e-g-char-int-void-td5118484.html
2. Update value reading in `ExternalArray` to unwrap one pointer after the other; and let the code generator for struct-field accessors generate code in a similar fashion.
3. Extend argument coercing in the plugin to accept arrays of the already supported arrays (i.e. `String` etc.)

Comment: Which reminds me that we could add conversion methods to `ExternalData` to create instances of `RawBitsArray` for pointers such as `int*`, `double*` etc. There is only one for C-String interpretation up to the NULL byte.

Comment: Considering this `**` discussion, it may be helpful to add a new subclass to `ExternalStruct` (or `ExternalObject`) to manage lists of pointers. `ExternalArray` could be an appropriate name.

Comment: On second thought, `ExternalDataArray` as a subclass of `ExternalData`would be more approriate. Note that plugin support would be needed if we want a return value like `int**` to automatically show up as such an array in image after an FFI call. Then, I suppose, one would have to extend `compiledSpec` to add an extra bit that indicates pointer-to-pointer in a type. But that may be overdoing it. In-image code can easily do the wrapping by calling a conversion method on `ExternalData` such as `#asArray`.

Comment: On third thought :-), there is no need for `ExternalDataArray`. We just need a mechanism to store the dimension of pointer arrays. Since mt.106, there is a simple protocol in `ExternalData` to read such arrays, including pointer arrays. See http://source.squeak.org/FFI/FFI-Kernel-mt.106.diff

Comment: Since mt.107, all the parsing of FFI pragmas is part of FFI-Kernel extension in Parser. Now we can figure out how to parse type names for multi-dimensional arrays to instances of `ExternalType`. See http://source.squeak.org/FFI/FFI-Kernel-mt.107.diff and also http://forum.world.st/FFI-Plugin-Question-about-multi-dimensional-arrays-e-g-char-int-void-td5118484.html

Comment: Since mt.108, there is also way to store size in `ExternalData` and a thin slice of the collection protocol to enumerate the elements: `do:`, `collect: `, `select:`, `reject:`. When reading the data, one pointer level should be dereferenced and followed. This only works for a single level at the moment. See http://source.squeak.org/FFI/FFI-Kernel-mt.108.diff